# Angular https call to self signed uri failing with "net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"

Tags: angular, https, self-signed

I am using Angular http module to make a call to a https endpoint enabled by self signed certificate.

The code is similar to what is showng below:

```
    export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private  http: HttpClient) {
 }
  title = 'my-app';
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.http.get('https://internalapp.com/context/apps/all').subscribe((res: any[]) => {
    console.log('sharief');
    console.log(res);
    });
  }
}
```

When angular application runs in chrome browser, it results in the error "net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID". This error occurs on this.http.get(...) method call.

Node's https module has an option shown below and it seems to work (from [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request):

```
var req = https.request({ 
      host: '192.168.1.1', 
      port: 443,
      path: '/',
      method: 'GET',
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      requestCert: true,
      agent: false
    },
```

Question: Is it possible to disable certificate validation during http.get call?

Answer (score 23):

Nope, This is a limitation from the browser.

You can put the back end url in your browser to tell your browser to authorise this call, it will then work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to understand what you said here.  Did you mean to say that I have to open another tab in the browser, copy the back-end-url, override the resulting browser warning?

Comment: Please ignore my follow-up question.  I found another link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51537394/how-to-add-selfsigned-certificate-to-chrome-mozilla which discusses the problem and suggested solution. May not be a good solution for sensitive and production environments.  Valid (not self signed) certificates should be used instead.

Comment: Your first question was right. If you think you can rephrase my answer, feel free to do it. My english is not perfect and I did my best to answer you ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I did first not fully understand the answer above. To make it clear to someone who is coming across this problem, I wanna show you what I did to solve the problem.

My Angular app is calling an API. The Browser does not trust the certificate of the API.

Solution:

- Copy URL from your API to Browser (what @Deblaton Jean-Phillipe said in his answer)
- Click next to URL on "not secure" (1), then click on "Your connection to this site isn't secure" (2)
  [image: Not trusted cert in Browser]
- On the following pop-up click on the certificate icon
  [image: Cert icon]
- This will show you the certificate. There you can click on details. At the bottom of the pop-up you can export it. Do that and save it somewhere you find it again.
- Install the certificate in Certifiacte store "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"

After that my angular application working again.

Comment: Cert thing worked for home page, nothing else, like scripts and other artifacts.