# https for a (java + angular) dev env on a local network causes CORS

Tags: java, angular, https, cors

I have the following "architecture":

- a java API / backoffice application on one computer
- an angular client application on another computer
- both are on the same local network for dev env, and both have a static IP

To test the application, the front application is calling the API using the computer IP: http://192.168.0.XY:ABCD/api

*ABCD = 8080 for http and 8443 for https*

All this is working fine as long as I'm having only http on dev env.
On prod env, https is working fine too.

Problem context:

- I have to use https for both API/back and client on dev side too
- on server side, the backoffice UI is working with https and I can use the backoffice features (I just have an alert because my certifcate is auto signed)
- on front side, I can see the homepage with https (with the same alert message for the same reason)

Problem is that when I try to connect on client UI, on dev side with https, it tries to call API, and fall into a CORS error.
Please note that the API allows both http and https origins:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:4200", "https://localhost:4200", "https://www.yodo.rip" })
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = {RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.POST})
public ResponseEntity<String> authenticate(@RequestBody String authParams) {...}
```

I spent 2 days on that problem, an hope to find some help here.

**[EDIT]**

- on server side, java is using a ".keystore" file, generated with keytool
- on front side, angular is using .crt + .key files generated with openssl
- in the client / API relationship, I don't know who doens't trust the other : client doesn't trust server's certificate ? or server doesn't trust client certificate ?

**[/EDIT]**

Answer (score -1):

thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642092/angular-https-call-to-self-signed-uri-failing-with-neterr-cert-authority-inva), I finally managed to log in.
The limitation was on browser side (both chrome and firefox).

To solve the problem, I had to try to login. When it failed:

1. I opened the developpers panel (press F12)
2. I right clicked on the query and choose "open in a new tab"
3. the broswer warned me: so I accepted to continue
4. the tab failed because there were no POST parameters (expected)
5. I closed the tab and tried again to log in